# onClick function triggered multiple time instead once in Material-ui table

Tags: reactjs, onclick, material-ui

The first problem, very evident, is that when I click on an object in the table the onClick function is called under each object, while I want "Tutorial full info" to be shown only under the clicked object.
Here's what the table looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySmHd.png)
So it is when I click on an object, in this case the first:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4beT6.png)
Another problem is that the columns in the table shift based on the object I click on.
For example if I click on the second it becomes like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze9Lq.png)

The code:

```
......

  <Table className="align-items-center table-flush" responsive>
                  <TableHead className="thead-light">
                    <TableRow>

                      <th scope="col">Project</th>
                      <th scope="col">Budget</th>
                      <th scope="col">Interest</th>
                      <th scope="col">Country</th>
                      <th scope="col">Score</th>
                      <th scope="col">Completion</th>
                      <th scope="col" />
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>


                    {tutorials &&
                      tutorials.map((tutorial, index) => (
                        <>
                          <TableRow
                            className={
                              "list-group-item " + (index === currentIndex ? "active" : "")
                            }
                            onClick={() => setActiveTutorial(tutorial, index)}
                            key={index}
                          >
                            <TableCell>{tutorial.title}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{tutorial.size}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{tutorial.country}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className="text-right">
                              <UncontrolledDropdown>
                                <DropdownToggle
                                  className="btn-icon-only text-light"
                                  href="#pablo"
                                  role="button"
                                  size="sm"
                                  color=""
                                  onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                                >
                                  <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v" />
                                </DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-arrow" right>
                                  <DropdownItem
                                    href="#pablo"
                                    onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                                  >
                                    Update
                                  </DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem
                                    href="#pablo"
                                    onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                                  >
                                    ...
                                  </DropdownItem>
                                  <DropdownItem
                                    href="#pablo"
                                    onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                                  >
                                    Delete
                                  </DropdownItem>
                                </DropdownMenu>
                              </UncontrolledDropdown>
                            </TableCell>
                          </TableRow>

                          <Grid
                            container
                            direction="column"
                            justify="center"
                            alignItems="stretch"
                          >
                            <ul className="col-md-6">
                              {currentTutorial ? (
                                <div>
                                  <h4>Tutorial Full Info</h4>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Title:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.title}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Country:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.country}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Business:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.business}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Size:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.size}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Wishlist:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.wishlist}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <label>
                                      <strong>Details:</strong>
                                    </label>{" "}
                                    {currentTutorial.detail}
                                  </div>

                                </div>
                              ) :  (
                                <span></span>
                              )}
                            </ul>

                          </Grid>
                        </>
                          ))}

                        </TableBody>
                      </Table>
......
```

Thanks to anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `currentTutorial ?`  to `(currentTutorial && currentIndex===index) ?`  should do the trick  in terms of only displaying the tutorial on the currently active item. The width of the column changes because if you insert an Element into the Table by default it only spans 1 column, therefore it extends the required width for your first columnn you could just wrap the `FullTutorial` in an a table Row like this.

```
{(currentTutorial && currentIndex===index) 
  && <TableRow>
     <TableCell colSpan = {6}> //colSpan = {6} tell the cell to span 6 columns
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          justify="center"
          alignItems="stretch"
        >
          <ul className="col-md-6">

            <div>
               <h4>Tutorial Full Info</h4>
               <div>
                  <label>
                     <strong>Title:</strong>
                  </label>{" "}
                  {currentTutorial.title}
               </div>
               //......
            </div>
          </ul>
        </Grid>
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>}
```